# Mongodb Java query for date range

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I needed to find all the records in mongo db within two date ranges using Mongo Driver[3.4.0] for Java.

Example:
I have **books** Collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acb40d27d63b61cb002bafe"),
    "title" : "WingsOfFire",
    "pub-date" : ISODate("2013-10-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "rel-date" : ISODate("2013-11-02T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Like above I have 100s of documents.

I need to find all records wherein pub-date > rel-date.

I am using Mongo DB version 3.2.6

I tried to use *$expr* operator but it seems to work with only Mongo 3.6+

Not able find cleaner solutions for above requirement.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where)-Operator:

```
db.books.find({ "$where": "this.pub-date > this.rel-date"});
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I use the above query with Java BasicDBObject class ?

Comment: You might want to consider the [limitations of `$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations) especially since the [aggregation framework can be used (via the MongoDB Java driver)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49734139/8200937) to produce the result you require.

Answer (score 3):

The MongoDB (prior to v3.4) shell command for your use case is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gt": [ "$pub-date", "$rel-date" ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Translating this command into Java you'll get:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = ...;

MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("...").getCollection("...");

List<Document> documents = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$redact", new Document("$cond",
                Arrays.asList(new Document("$gt", Arrays.asList("$pub-date", "$rel-date")), "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE"))
        ))).into(new ArrayList<>());

for (Document document : documents) {
    System.out.println(document.toJson());
}
```

Given a collection with these documents ...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acb40d27d63b61cb002bafe"),
    "title" : "WingsOfFire",
    "pub-date" : ISODate("2013-10-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "rel-date" : ISODate("2013-11-02T00:00:00.000Z")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acb662756539a6734e64e4a"),
    "title" : "WingsOfSmoke",
    "pub-date" : ISODate("2013-11-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "rel-date" : ISODate("2013-10-02T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

.. the above Java code will print ...

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5acb662756539a6734e64e4a" }, "title" : "WingsOfSmoke", "pub-date" : { "$date" : 1383350400000 }, "rel-date" : { "$date" : 1380672000000 } }
```

... because this document's `pub-date` (2013-11-02T00:00:00.000Z) is after its `rel-date` (2013-10-02T00:00:00.000Z).

Note: the `$where` operator is functionally equivalent but use of that operator comes with some [limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations):

> `$where` evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., `$gt`, `$in`).
>
> In general, you should use `$where` only when you can’t express your query using another operator. If you must use `$where`, try to include at least one other standard query operator to filter the result set. Using `$where` alone requires a collection scan.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.