# How to use $where with $or in mongo db?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have following *books* collection.

*Example:*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acb4f817d63b61cb002bb01"),
    "title" : "Book3",
    "pubDate" : ISODate("2019-10-05T00:01:00.000Z"),
    "relDate" : ISODate("2019-10-04T00:01:10.000Z"),
    "place" : "Mysore"
}
```

Here my requirement is to "List out all books where (field *place* is present AND (*pubDate* > *relDate* OR either or both of *pubDate*/*relDate* not present) ".
I tried with following query, but it seems something is missing here.

```
{$and: [ {place: {$exists: true}}, { '$where': {$or:[{'this.pubDate > this.relDate'}, {pubDate: {$exists: false}}, {relDate: {$exists: false}}] }} ] }
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting ':' but found '}'.
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:345)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readArray(DBObjectCodec.java:335)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:291)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:347)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:347)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readArray(DBObjectCodec.java:335)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readValue(DBObjectCodec.java:291)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.readDocument(DBObjectCodec.java:347)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.decode(DBObjectCodec.java:138)
    at com.mongodb.DBObjectCodec.decode(DBObjectCodec.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.parse(BasicDBObject.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.parse(BasicDBObject.java:62)
    at com.test.MongoTest.main(MongoTest.java:59)
```

I need to use *$where* clause as I can't use aggregate operations with existing code setup.

Mongo Version: 3.2.6

Please clarify.

Comment: any error ? or no results ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Updated the question with exception.

Comment: "I need to use $where clause as I can't use aggregate operations with existing code setup." ... your accompany [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732308/mongodb-java-query-for-date-range) includes an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49734139/8200937) which shows the use of aggregation instead of `$where` and that answer **is** valid for MongoDB v3.2.6

Comment: I agree. But my current code setup doesn't allow me to use aggregate clause.

Comment: You are using MongoDB server v3.2.6 and MongoDB Java driver v3.4 ... both of which allow the use of aggregation pipelines. So, can you explain this statement:  "my current code setup doesn't allow me to use aggregate clause"?

Comment: @glytching Thanks for the reply. Currently in my setup, it is like create BasicDBObjects of all possible queries -> Collect all of them into a List -> Create a final BasicDBObject from the List -> pass on BasicDBObject to Collection.find() API.

Comment: I don't see a way to use aggregate with Collection.find().

Comment: `find` and `aggregate` are spearate methods on the collection object in the MongoDB Java driver so perhaps you need to revisit your code to create a separate path which allows for the use of `aggregate` where that's the optimal choice for the given expression. MongoDB does not recommend the use of `$where` (the resons for this are outlined in the *very* similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49732308/8200937) you created before this one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{
  "$and":[
    {"place":{"$exists":true}},
    {"$or":[
      {"$where":'this.pubDate > this.relDate'},
      {"pubDate":{"$exists":false}},
      {"relDate":{"$exists":false}}
    ]}
  ]
}
```

You dont need to `$and`. you can simplify to

```
{
  "place":{"$exists":true},
  "$or":[
    {"$where":'this.pubDate > this.relDate'},
    {"pubDate":{"$exists":false}},
    {"relDate":{"$exists":false}}
  ]
}
```